# htaccess Redirect to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have below url

```
   www.site.com/Photo/Actor/ActorName/GalleryName/2
```

Here 
**Photo** and **Actor** are static strings in url
**ActorName** and **GalleryName**'s are dynamic
**2** is the photo index..

How can i Redirect this url patten to the following

```
    www.site.com/Actor/ActorName/GalleryName/Photo/2
```

I am changing my site url format.
my site is already well crawled and well indexed in google so i want to redirect the urls to new format so currently indexed urls do not die.

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` already in place? Are you using any CMS like WordPress or similar?

Comment: yes. using .htaccess i am currently implementing all redirects. Not using CMS.

Comment: sure.. implementing it current..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically rewrite it as follow:

```
RewriteRule ^(Photo)/(Actor)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$2/$3/$4/$1/$5 [R=302,NC,L]
```

To further explain it:

```
^(Photo)/(Actor)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$
```

This means, if it starts with `Photo/Actor/ActorName/GalleryName/Numbers`.

Then redirect to `Actor/ActorName/GalleryName/Photo/Numbers` using a 301 permanent redirect.

The `/$2/$3/$4/$1/$5` means the reordering of the above mentioned.

---

Keep in mind I am using `R=302` on the above code and you should also use `R=302` until you confirm it is fully working to your needs, then you can safely switch it to `R=301`.

This is to prevent your browser from getting cached with previous attempts so you can see whether its working or not until make it definitive.

If you already done previous attempts, I suggest you to use a different browser to test the URL preferable one that you haven't used to access the site to make sure its not accessing cached information.

Comment: Perfect. This redirect is working.. Not an expert on htaccess. learning it.

Comment: @ChiranjeeviPadala glad it worked for you :) here is a good introduction to mod_rewrite if you want to read and learn more. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^Photo/Actor/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)  Actor/$1/$2/Photo/$3  [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
    <?php

header("Location: http://www.mydomain. com/new-page.html", true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

To know more: http://prowpexpert.com/